# Dynamically create Python object from JSON returned by REST API

Tags: python, rest, object

Say I have two REST API endpoints (`http://example.com/task`, `http://example.com/employee`) and the following two classes:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.ID = kwargs['ID']
        self.first_name = kwargs['first_name'] if 'first_name' in kwargs else None
        self.last_name = kwargs['last_name'] if 'last_name' in kwargs else None

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.ID = kwargs['ID']
        self.start_date = kwargs['start_date']
        self.employee = Employee(ID=kwargs['employee_id'])
```

I now want to create Python objects from the json returned by the REST API.

Say that a GET to `http://example.com/task/19` returns the following json:

```
json_data =  {'ID': '19', 'start_date': '2018-04-23', 'employee_id': 'xyz1223'}
task = Task(**json_data)
```

Now, the following all work

```
print(task.ID) # 19
print(task.start_date) # 2018-04-23
print(task.employee.ID) # xyz1223
```

but `print(task.employee.first_name)` returns `None`. What I would like to happen is that under the hood a GET request to `http://example.com/employee/xyz1223` is sent, that the resulting json is parsed, and that the attributes `first_name` and `last_name` are filled in.

What is the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Get something that works first, *then* worry about whether it is Pythonic.

Comment: Not your question but `kwargs['first_name'] if 'first_name' in kwargs else None` could be `kwargs.get('first_name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the `__init__` methods as simple and as stupid as possible,
which means *no* I/O. That work is deferred to a class method named `from_api`, which just takes the requested ID as an argument, then builds the appropriate URI, parses the output, and passes the necessary data to
the call to `__init__`.

`Employee.from_api` is still pretty simple, but `Task.from_api` is where you implement the "join" by calling `Employee.from_api` with an argument taken from the parsed task JSON data.

```
class Employee(object):
    BASE_URL = "http://example.com/employee/"

    def __init__(self, id_, first, last):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last

    @classmethod
    def from_api(cls, id_):
        url = cls.BASE_URL + id_
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        return Employee(id_=id_
                        first=json_data.get('first_name'),
                        last=json_data.get('last_name'))


class Task(object):
    BASE_URL = "http://example.com/task/"

    def __init__(self, id_, start_date, emp):
        self.ID = id_
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.employee = emp

    @classmethod
    def from_api(cls, id_):
        url = cls.BASE_URL + id_
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        emp = Employee.from_api(json_data['employee_id'])
        return Task(id_, json_data['start_date'], emp)


task = Task.from_api("19")
```

---

Such a design is well-suited to Python 3.7's forthcoming [data classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    id_: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    BASE_URL: ClassVar[str] = "http://example.com/employee/"


    @classmethod
    def from_api(self, id_):
        # same as above


@dataclass
class Task:
    id_: str
    start_data: str  # Or maybe datetime.date, depending on your design
    employee: Employee

    BASE_URL: ClassVar[str] = "http://example.com/task/"

    @classmethod
    def from_api(self, id_):
        # same as above
```